# What happens when a vector is subtracted from a given point?

Tags: geometry, vectors

**I am specifically looking for a description of subtracting a Vector from a given Point, like the one I have found [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/points_and_vectors.html) for addition of a Point and a Vector.**

> Point+Vector Addition
>   Definition
>
> Q=P+ $\vec v$=($p_i$+$v_i$)
>
> The resulting point Q is considered to be the displacement, or “translation”, of the point P in the direction of and by the magnitude of the vector v=Q-P.

[Here](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vch03/vch03_20.html) I found a good example which gives a fair idea about whats happening behind addition of vector and a point.

Couldnt find the same for subtraction.

Comment: Subtracting a vector $\vec v$ is the same as adding $- \vec v$ (which is $\vec v$ pointing in the exact opposite direction).

Comment: @bp99: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that subtracting a vector $\vec v$ from something is the same as adding $-\vec v$ to it. And $-\vec v$ is $\vec v$ pointing in the exact opposite direction.

Therefore if you know how to add vectors, you know how to subtract them as well: just take $-\vec v$ and add it, the way you would add any other vector.

Comment: According to this, Can I conclude that when doing operations on a point with vectors , One must consider point as a position vector?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, there is no such operation as "subtracting a vector from a point".  You can only add or subtract a vector from another vector.

Comment: @user247327: In an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) you can certainly add a vector to a point or subtract a vector from a point; you can even subtract two points to get a vector. What you cannot do is add two points.